# Lenovo and Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics

I am thinking about buying a new Lenovo laptop which uses the Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics.
I am not seeing anything here on that driver and 21.10 and if it works out of the box.
I am currently using a laptop with AMD graphics which does not work with 21.10 and no additional drivers are found in software/additional drivers.
Is there a list of supported graphics somewhere?
Thanks in advance. Bob

Thanks you, That would seem to say it will work out of the box with 21.10.

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Answer (score 1):

According to Intel's documentation, drivers for Xe graphics are already integrated into the Linux kernel.

There is additional documentation for setting up other configurations using this driver with a discreet Xe MAX driver (using both integrated and discreet Intel Xe GPUs).

See: [Intel® Iris® Xe MAX Graphics with Linux](https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/devices/iris-xe-max-graphics/index.html)

Comment: Does not work "Out of the Box" on my Lenovo Ideapad 5i Pro with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  Video is choppy and flashes on and off with mouse movement.